# static table creation in grafana for visualization

Tags: grafana

i am wondering whether there is a provision in grafana to just create a static table without getting any data from a datasource ?

I need help to create something like a static html table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use text panel and create static markdown/html table - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/text-panel/

Comment: one more question @jan, can i include a panel in a html table ? i mean lets say <td>CPU></td><td>-- panel -- </td> something like this ?

Comment: @Jason It depens what is a "panel"?

Comment: could you please elaborate ?

Comment: I mean i want to include a mini image if a another graph in the text like <td>CPU</td><td><CPU mini panel showing usage></td> something like this